# How to Select a option in ReactSelect on Page Load

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am using reactSelect to filter the results, I want to open the filtered Results in new Tab which is working properly but i am unable to select the selected option in new Tab.

```
<ReactSelect
            options={getAuthorValueOptions}
            onChange={(v) => addFilter({ userId: v.value })}
            values={[get(allfilters, 'userId', null)]}
            onInputChange={(v) => setKeyword(v)}
            loading={loadingOptions}
            name="Search Seller"
        />
const getAuthorValueOptions = useMemo(() => {
    const parsedOptions = options
    if (selectedUser) {
        const { firstName, lastName, _id } = selectedUser
        const index = options.findIndex((o) => o.value === selectedUser._id)
        if (index === -1) {
            parsedOptions.push({ label: firstName + ' ' + lastName, value: _id })
        }
    }
    return parsedOptions
}, [options, selectedUser])
```

here options are coming from an API

Comment: When you say "unable to select the selected option in new Tab", what do you mean exactly? Is there another select on that page? And, what is the `values` prop you've placed on the select? React-Select doesn't have a `values` prop, according to the documentation. Also, I'm a little confused by your `getAuthorValueOptions`. This appears to be a variable, but you've named it like a function. Are you trying to filter the options displayed to those of your `selectedUser`? (Which I'm guessing is a separate value somewhere)

Comment: BTW, if `options` are coming from an API, then you probably want to use the `AsyncSelect` version of React-Select.